# Using TypeScript With jQuery Without AMD?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to use TypeScript and jQuery (or any other non-Node JavaScript library) without AMD?

Currently my code compiles fine, but the compiled code cannot see the jQuery's `$` function.

Given this TypeScript code:

```
/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />
import $ = require('jquery');

export class Widget {
  foo() { 
    $(selector).bar()
  }
}
```

I'd like the following JavaScript:

```
var Widget = (function ($) {
  function Widget() { }
  Widget.prototype.foo = function () { ... };
  return Widget;
})(jQuery);
```

Currently my code *does not* have `jQuery` passed to the anonymous function.

### UPDATE 1

Per @basarat

> Do it by hand. If its valid JavaScript then its valid TypeScript

You're suggesting (and I was thinking) that I do this:

```
var Widget = (function($) {
  class Widget {
    foo() {
      $('body').append('foo');
    }
  }
  return Widget;
})(jQuery);
```

?

That's not valid TypeScript and without that, I'm left with prototypes.

### UPDATE 2

Per @basarat the above is supported with TypeScript 1.6.

Comment: I know I can do this *by hand*. I want to know if there's a TypeScript way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given this TypeScript code , I'd like the following JavaScript

**This is not how the TypeScript js *emit* is designed to work**.

So in short : no. You can't get this javascript from that typescript.

> I know I can do this by hand. I want to know if there's a TypeScript way to do this.

Do it by hand. If its valid JavaScript then its valid TypeScript. There isn't a specific TypeScript way to do this thing. The *JavaScript way* is *the TypeScript way* in this case.

## Update

> That's not valid TypeScript and without that, I'm left with prototypes.

It is valid TypeScript starting with TypeScript `1.6`.

Comment: Checkout the update to my question. Looks like to do it by hand I loose `class`, `interface`, etc... keywords

Comment: See update. It should work starting with typescript 1.6

Comment: Yup, 1.6 works. Do you know if this was added to 1.6 to support this problem?

Comment: This as well as others. More important was *anonymous classes* (e.g. class expressions) and *inner classes*.